# ProgessBar vs Seekbar in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, seekbar, android-progressbar

I want a screen with one to many entries where the bar gets bigger and smaller based upon user entries.  The user will NOT have access to manually drag the bar.

I've played with a `ProgressBar` but it seems that this is mainly used for file downloads.  `SeekBar` seems more geared for controlling volume and other android features.  This is really not what I want to do.  What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> This is really not what I want to do. What is the best way to do this?

There is no best way to do that. The `ProgressBar` and `SeekBar` are the only widgets in the Android SDK that you can use for that bar. So unless you write your own widget that does everything that you want you'll have to use one of them(which I don't see why would be a problem).

> I've played with a progress bar but it seems that this is mainly used
>   for file downloads. Seekbar seems more geared for controlling volume
>   and other android features.

This aren't really issues as you always have the ability to disable the widgets so the user doesn't have the option of messing with them.